# How to set Password property for DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have used `DataGridView` to implement username-password UI. The passwords are shown in `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` type column. How can I use the existing code for `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and implement password property for the text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handle the `EditingControlShowing` event and then cast the editing control to a `TextBox` and manually set the `UseSystemPasswordChar` to true:

```
TextBox passwordText = e.Control as TextBox;
if (passwordText != null)
{
    passwordText.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
}
```

## Edit

Could you try this :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == “passwordDataGridViewTextBoxColumn” && e.Value != null)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Tag = e.Value;
        e.Value = new String(‘*’, e.Value.ToString().Length);
    }
}
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Tag != null)
        e.Control.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This one works as long as I am editing the text inside text Box, I see that the password char vanishes as soon as I move to a different cell. Please help.

Comment: It works!!! I also set passwordText.PasswordChar = '*' inside dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```
if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
{
    if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Password" && e.Value != null)
    {
        dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Tag = e.Value;
        e.Value = new String('\u2022', e.Value.ToString().Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show how to have your code called on the Cell_Formatting event to make the answer more complete?