# Masking password column in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, passwords, datagridviewcolumn, datagridtextcolumn

I'm having problem with masking the password column. The code below works, but it doesnt work the way I want. While editing it do mask the password but when I am done and continue to the next datagridviewcell password becomes visible.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{            
        if (  dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 10)//select target column
        {
            TextBox textBox = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            }                
        }
        var txtBox = e.Control as TextBox;
        txtBox.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(underlyingTextBox_KeyDown);
        txtBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(underlyingTextBox_KeyDown);
}
```

Also in edit mode it should have mask only the columns with index 5 && 10 however it masks all columns.
I cannot solve these issues, any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried by changing(Textbox as Password in Properties of Textbox) in UI ?

Comment: Can I do that by code, because actually there is no textbox, it is datagridview cell's textBox. I dont know how to change textbox's propertis from design view.

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953425/how-to-set-password-property-for-datagridviewtextboxcolumn

Comment: I tried that one already this is not what I exactly try to do. I'm trying that while typing the password characters must be shown as passwordchar  like " * ". However in that case after you done with the cell program masks the password. @NamBình

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.ColumnIndex == 5 || e.ColumnIndex == 10) && e.Value != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Tag = e.Value;
                e.Value = new String('\u25CF', e.Value.ToString().Length);
            }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 10)//select target column
        {
            TextBox textBox = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox textBox = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
            }
        }
        var txtBox = e.Control as TextBox;
        txtBox.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(underlyingTextBox_KeyDown);
        txtBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(underlyingTextBox_KeyDown);
    }
```

Comment: else
            {
                textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
            }

This is a good trick, it works now thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the the name of your DataGridView is dataGridView1 and the password column is 1, add this to CellFormatting:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Value != null)
    {
        e.Value = new String('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution

Comment: In newer version of the DataGridView control, cell values are automatically shown as tooltips when cursor moves on them. To ultimately hide values through these tooltips, set tooltips off using command `grid.ShowCellToolTips = false;`