# Getting the design of the data from ms access to my datagridview c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I'm new to this and I hope you get me, As you can see in the picture, the rows inside the column password have mask, my question is how can I copy that design inside my datagridview?

[Click here to see my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qipJG.png)

This is my code on how I retrieve does data and inserted it into my datagrid view.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace GoldenToolsThesisProject
    {
        public partial class FrmSetup : Form
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        }
        private void FrmSetup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database1.accdb;
                                    Persist Security Info = True";
DisplayData();
        }
        private void DisplayData()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM People";

                OleDbDataAdapter Adptr = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet Table = new DataSet();
                Adptr.Fill(Table);
                DataGridView1.DataSource = "";
                DataGridView1.DataSource = Table.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

[Here's my DataGridView1 output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIvIz.png)

I want to get the design in column password into my datagridview so it can't be visible when opened. I hope someone could help me with this. This keeps me up for days and I don't know the answer.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Dis this answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400177/masking-password-column-in-datagridview?

Comment: THANKSS!!But there is a problem, I just need to mask one specific column, how can I do that? @EugeneKomisarenko

Comment: OH WAIT I GOT IT, THANKS AGAIN @EugeneKomisarenko I GOT THE ANSWER!!! THANK YOU!!!