# How to format DataGridView to password characters?

Tags: c#

**Goal:**

My goal is to format 1 column to password characters `*`.

**Resources I have tried:**

I have used an example from here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.8

and tried this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38074239/12485722

**This is my current code to load DataGrid View:**

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshGrid();
}



//Refresh Data Grid from external Forms
public void RefreshGrid()
{
    // MySQL connection string
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
    {
        using (var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from user", conn))
        {
            using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
            {
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This simply loads up the DataGridView with Usernames and passwords.

Now I need to format 2nd column to password characters, so the passwords do not show as text but formatted as `*`.

I have tried adding this piece of code from the 2nd resource mentioned above:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Value != null)
    {
        e.Value = new String('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);
    }
}
```

This does not work - no errors show up, but I have noticed this references is set to 0.

(Note: this is what it should be)

[image]

**Question:**

I am confused where it is going wrong.. can somebody assist me to achieve this task?

**Update (1) - Events and cell formatting not showing:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to handle EditingControlShowing event,
in this event set property 'UseSystemPasswordChar' of e.Control item (you can cast it to TextBox for example), to 'true'.

Comment: About the lack of reference: have you added your event method to fire up on gridview in right event name? Check it in designer, probably its not wired in properties>events>CellFormatting, you should have the value dataGridView1_CellFormatting:. It should be saved in designer.cs file, which is partial class of your Form.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik there is no events in properties, and same for cell formatting. I have noticed that too. Im kinda confused why it's not whowing up

Comment: Connections between events and methods  are saved in designer.cs file of your form, which is partial class of your form. Everything should be saved in those both files, but you shouldnt modify the designer.cs file manually, designer already do it for you.

Comment: click the yellow lighting bolt to show events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is not wired to an event of GridView (thats why it has 0 references, because nothing is using your function).

The solution in the mentioned link is correct, but you should wire your method to an event in designer (right click on grid view > properties > events) and choose an event to fire up in CellFormatting event. Also dont forget to handle EditingControlShowing, but everything what you need is already written in a solution thread that you mentioned.

Comment: when you click yellow lighting bolt, you will see events there...

Comment: got it, never knew this. Thank you

Comment: im glad i could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you modify your query to just say the below:

`select username, repeat('*', length(password)) from users`